# Найти элементы в строке и преобразовать их в теги

Tags: javascript, регулярные-выражения

есть строка в которой есть ссылки и хештеги. Нужно обернуть эти ссылки в тег `<a href=""></a>` как и хештеги. Но не пойму почему с ссылкой не корректно работает и один хештег не находит который находится без пробела. Вот мой пример:

```js
var link = /(https?:\/\/|ftp:\/\/|www\.)((?![.,?!;:()]*(\s|$))[^\s]){2,}/gim
var hashTag = /(^|\s)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig

function rebaseText(text) {
  if (typeof text === 'string') {
    if (text.match(link)) {
      text = text.replace(link, "$1<a href={$2} class='link'>$2</a>");
    }
    if (text.match(hashTag)) {
      text = text.replace(hashTag, "$1<a href='https://google.com/search?q=$2' class='hashtag'>$2</a>");
    }
  }
  return text;
}

console.log(rebaseText('Hello world!!! https://google.com/ some text http://myweb.com/ lorem #hashTag1#hashTag2 qweqwewqeqweq #hashTag3'));
```

Comment: попробуйте добавить * в регулярное выражение `var hashTag = /(^|\s*)(#[a-z\d-]+)/ig`

Comment: @Vladimir спасибо, с хештегом получилось, так же получилось и с линкой, ответ оставлю чуть позже.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил это так, надеюсь в будущем кому-то пригодиться:

```js
const hashTag = /(^|\s*)(#[a-z_а-і-я\d-]+)/ig;
const link = /(\b(https?|):\/\/[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;]*[-A-Z0-9+&@#\/%=~_|])/ig;
const newLink = /(^|[^\/])(www\.[\S]+(\b|$))/gim;

function rebaseText(content) {
  let elementСontent = content.replace(link, "<a href='$1' target='_blank'>$1</a>");
  let newContent = elementСontent.replace(newLink, '$1 <a target="_blank" href="http://$2" class="news-link">$2</a>');
  if (newContent.match(hashTag)) {
    newContent = newContent.replace(hashTag, replacer);
  }
  return newContent;
}

function replacer(str, p1, p2) {
  return `<a target='_blank' href="https://www.google.com/search?q=${encodeURIComponent(p2)}" class='news-link'>${str}</a>`;
};

console.log(rebaseText('Hello world http://google.com/ #helloWorld#Tag2 test#tag3 https://google.com/'))
```